# Kivy: How to display a ScrollView from an custom BoxLayout?

Tags: python, kivy, scrollview, kivy-language

I need to create a list of items with a custom row layout. Every row should have an image, one main button and two other small buttons (side by side), after pressing the main button I would like to display a short text in a scroll view under the row. 
I am using a custom BoxLayout that looks like this:

```
<InfoRow@BoxLayout>:
landmarkName: self.landmarkName
pozaId: self.pozaId
rowId: self.rowId
starId: self.starId
svId: self.svId

show_infoId: self.show_infoId
orientation: 'vertical'
size_hint_y: None
height:self.minimum_height

BoxLayout:
    size_hint_y: None
    height: 50
    pos_hint: {"x": 0, 'top': 1}

    AsyncImage: 
        size_hint_x: 0.2
        id: root.pozaId
        source: root.srcImg

    ToggleButton:
        id: root.rowId
        font_size: self.height * 0.5
        text_size: self.size 
        text: root.landmarkName
        on_release: root.toggle_info()

    ToggleButton:
        #on_release: self.parent.parent.ids.calc_input.text += self.text
        size_hint: None, None
        width: 50
        height: 50
        background_down: 'data/check.png'
        background_normal: 'data/full_plus.png'

    ToggleButton:
        id: root.starId
        size_hint: None, None
        height: 50
        width: 50
        background_down: root.starImg
        background_normal: root.starImg
        on_release: root.saveLocation() 

ScrollView:
    id: root.svId
    size_hint_y: None
    pos_hint: {"x": 0.12, 'top': 1}
    height: 0

    InfoTextInput:
        id: root.show_infoId
        text: ""
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
```

And my python code:

```
class InfoRow(BoxLayout):
pozaId = StringProperty(' ')
rowId = StringProperty(' ')
starId = StringProperty(' ')
svId= StringProperty(' ')
show_infoId=StringProperty(' ')
landmarkName = StringProperty(' ')
pressed = False
starImg = StringProperty('data/white.png')
srcImg = StringProperty('data/white.png')

def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(InfoRow, self).__init__(**kwargs)

def toggle_info(self):

    self.pressed = not self.pressed
    if self.pressed:
        height = self.height * .25
    else:
        height = 0

    Animation(height=height, d=.25, t='out_quart').start(
            self.ids[self.svId])

    if not self.pressed:
        self.ids[self.show_infoId].focus = False
        return

    self.ids[self.show_infoId].text = "TO DO"
    self.ids[self.svId].scroll_y = 1

def saveLocation(self):
    pass
```

Where I create my list:

class MainScreen(Screen):

```
def getSpecificInfo(self, category):

    ...

    self.ids["extraInfo"].clear_widgets()
    for i in range (0, 15):
        wid = InfoRow(pozaId = pozaId, landmarkName=landmarkName, starImg = starImg ,rowId = rowId, starId = starId, svId= svId, show_infoId=show_infoId)
        self.ids["extraInfo"].add_widget(wid)
```

For now I managed to create dynamically my list, but after pressing the button the ScrollView doesn't show and I have the following error:

`self.ids[self.svId])
 KeyError: 'sv0'`

I have no idea what I am doing wrong.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

## Problem - KeyError

```
self.ids[self.svId])
 KeyError: 'sv0'
```

### Root Cause

It means that the value, `'sv0'` in `self.svId` does not exist in *`self.ids`* dictionary type property.

### Note

Widget created dynamically in Python code, the `id` assigned to the widget is not added to `self.ids`. You might want to create your own dictionary to store them for accessing it later.

Comment: Can you tell me what information should I store in the dictionary and how to access the ScrollView from it?  I suppose I should store the id and the widget before adding it to my layout, but I'm not sure how I can access the ScrollView, or maybe I can insert the row layout and the scrollview separately?